# How to globally hide/show the mouse cursor in Windows, programmatically?

Tags: windows, mouse, mouse-cursor

In some applications, such as  Notepad, when you start typing, the mouse cursor disappears.  Then as soon as you move the mouse, the cursor reappears.  This is great, because a lot of the time, the mouse cursor gets in the way of typing, especially when using large inverted cursors.

However, this doesn't work in *most* modern applications; only those that use common Windows controls like the textarea control.

I want to create an app that runs in the background, which globally listens for any keypress, no matter which app is in the foreground, and hides the mouse pointer until the mouse is physically moved again.

I have tried searching everywhere, but every solution either does nothing at all, or only hides the cursor when it is over the test application's window (not for all windows).  I tried ChatGPT and it provides broken solutions that don't work.  I have tried "solutions" in AutoHotkey, C#, C++ with no luck.

I don't care what programming language is used, as long as this can be achieved.  Please do not post solutions that only hide the cursor for the app itself.  The cursor must disappear, regardless of which app has focus, and regardless of where the cursor is located, when any keyboard key is pressed.  Once the mouse is moved, the cursor should reappear where it last existed (should not be teleported somewhere else).

The HideCursor() function of windows.h does not work.  CreateCursor/SetSystemCursor do not work.  Running the script/app as Administrator does not work.

My current solution is to simply *move* the cursor about 100px away from its current spot. This *usually* gets it out of the way of typing, but sometimes it then hovers over something else that pops up in the way, so it's not an optimal solution.

MANY THANKS for any working suggestions.

Comment: Nobody?  Is this really as hard as it seems?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind losing the ability to click, a possible solution would be to create a small transparent window and set it to be in top-most mode using `SetWindowPos`.

Then, Hide the cursor in it (or change the shape to a transparent pixel).

Get the cursor position using `GetCursorPos`, then make a loop that keeps updating the window position to match that of the cursor.

With this setup the cursor doesn't get out of the region that hides it.

Note: Don't forget to add half the size of the window to the mouse position so it is in the center.